# Spring Security 5 does not seem to handle OAuth2 access token expirations - asks the user to login again

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am reading the tutorial at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ on how to create an Oauth2 login page and using a client to access protected resources. The source for that tutorial is [on github](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2).

But the tutorial doesn´t seem to handle the situation when the access token from Github is expired. When the access token has been expired I expect Spring Security to handle it so I can keep making requests to Github. But instead I have to login again to gain a new access token.

What do I need to do to get Spring Security to get a new access token from the refresh token when the access token has been expired?

Comment: How did you expire the token  so that you find it is not working?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai: I noticed it when the token expired by itself (8 hours). Then I was redirected to the login page instead of that Spring Boot should refresh the token. Or does `HttpSecurity.oauth2Login()` just authorize and construct the `Authentication` principal and then it is up to the developer to refresh the token? Or should Spring Security handle the token refresh out of the box? If the latter, why does it not do that in the sample app by spring.io?

Comment: It is not possible for spring security because spring security does not keep any track of who you are. Only thing it knows is your current session is associated with the token. So if you token expired while your session is active, it should use the refresh token to get the new access token. But once you logout and login again, spring security does not know you are related to the previous token. Hope  it makes sense

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai: now you said something! I didn´t get that the spring session was the thing the token was related to, so when the session times out of inactivity, then the oauth2 token is abolished. I tried to set the session timeout to 1 minute and I had to login again. Is there any magic to let Spring hold the token between sessions or is it up to the developer to fix it?

Comment: You should not try to fix it because the purpose is to your spring boot application does not keep any of your security data. It is exactly like username and password but without providing the password directly. If your session times out, you have to login again. It is the same thing and difference is you are logging in with GitHub.

Comment: What about `rememberMe()`? Is it not the way to keep the token between sessions?

Comment: `rememberMe()` is not to remember your session. It keeps your username and password in cookie. But here the username and password is for GithHub. You could build some custom solution where after successful login, spring security adds a cookie with those tokens. But then you have to build a custom pre authentication filter which takes the cookie do the rest of the stuff without asking you to login